# Problem about kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am new to python and kivymd and I am trying to develop a program for data entry. However, when I create a drop-down menu for a selection,  an error occurred and I can't update the value of the text field after I select an item.
Here is the python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
class AMRMenu(Screen):
    def GIbutton(self):
        sm.current = 'GI'
class GIWindow(Screen):
    weather = ObjectProperty(None)
    menu_weather_items = [{"text":"Sunny"},{"text":"Cloudy"},{"text":"Raining"}]
    menu_FeedResponse_items=[{"text":"High"},{"text":"Medium"},{"text":"Low"}]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
                    items=self.menu_weather_items, 
                    width_mult=4,
                    caller = self.weather,
                    callback=self.set_item)
    def set_item(self, instance):
        def set_item(interval):
            self.weather.text = instance.text
            self.menu.dismiss()
        Clock.schedule_once(set_item, 0.5) 
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
sm = WindowManager()    

class MainApp(MDApp):   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        kv = Builder.load_file("FR.kv")
    def build(self):        
        screens = [AMRMenu(name = "menu"), GIWindow(name = "GI")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)
        sm.current = "menu"
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And here is the kv. file:

```
<AMRMenu>:
    name:"menu"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Main Menu"
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "General Information"
                on_press: root.GIbutton()
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Water Temperature"
            OneLineListItem
                text: "Feeding Amount"
            OneLineListItem: 
                text: "Residue and Feeding response"
            OneLineListItem: 
                text: "Dead fish"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Sell/Use"

<GIWindow>
    name: "GI"

    weather: weather
    ScrollView:
        id: screen
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            adaptive_height: True

            MDTextField:
                id: weather
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                hint_text: "Weather"
                icon_right: "arrow-down-drop-circle-outline"
                input_filter: lambda text, from_undo: text[:5 - len(self.text)]
                on_focus: root.menu.open()
```

Here is the error message:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1297, in add_widget
 (widget, widget.parent)
 kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivymd.uix.menu.MDDropdownMenu object at 0x7fd2fa31a6e0> to window, it already has a parent <kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7fd2f65826e0>
```

I don't know why I made this happen. It helps a lot if someone figures it out. Thank you for reading this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `kv` line:

```
on_focus: root.menu.open()
```

is opening the menu every time the `focus` changes. So, it tries to open the menu even when the `focus` becomes false. An easy fix is to just open the menu when `focus is` True`:

```
on_focus: if self.focus: root.menu.open()
```